# Regex for string property

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to get regex for my `ValidationAttribute`.

Allowed value must be `alphabet` + `numeric` + "`_`" + "`-`" + "`.`".
The value must start and end with number and alphabet only.

Examples:

- `"1abc-def"` should work
- `"abc-1def"` should work
- `"-abc-def"` should fail
- `"abc-def."` should fail
- `"a bc-def"` should fail

Comment: Can you give us some example scenarios that would apply to your rule?

Comment: It seems as if you already have everything that you need. With a quick glance at the RegEx reference and a few tests with [RegEx101](http://regex101.com) you _should_ be able to write the RegEx yourself.

Comment: @ben I'm newbie and dont understand regex

Comment: @xufox thanks for the reference. I'll try that.

Comment: @flipybitz I need to validate value supplied by user for ProductNo, InvoiceNo, etc

Comment: I mean post a literal example of something that would match your regex. Reading your credentials, would `"1t2e3s4t5"` work?

Comment: So would regex `/(\w|\n|[-_.])+/` work?

Comment: did you want to match `a` ?

Comment: Why would the question get downvoted? I think the question can help others that have the same problem. I'm really a newbie to regex

Comment: @Reynaldi You'll stay a newbie to regex if you just post your required output without trying *anything* yourself, or putting in any effort. Your requirement is very simple, and you should be able to do it yourself by reading even a small amount about how to write regexes.

Comment: @Rob Fair enough. Thanks for your input. I was just in hurry due to bugs in my apps and have to push the fix as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Note: **`\w`** match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/vQ1tE5/1)

You can also use below regex to match a single character or number:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```